# Return the Key Value of a struct within a KSQL persistent query stream

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

So let's say I have the following data format as a type of MAP<VARCHAR,VARCHAR>:

```
{
"Field1": {
    "varchar_value_i_want": {
        "val1": 1,
        "val2": 2,
        "val3": 3
    },
    "varchar_value_i_also_want": {
        "val1": 1,
        "val2": 2,
        "val3": 3
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way to extract the varchar_value_i_want and varchar_value_i_also_want as a separate property? I checked the Confluent/Kafka documentation but didn't really get a clear answer if it's possible in the current version.

Comment: You should be able to SELECT both entries from one map, yes. Have you tried anything in particular? What version are you using?

Comment: That is no issue, but if I want the VARCHAR value of the Key as a separate property e.g. someProperty: varchar_value_i_want. The Confluent documentation isn't too clear on if this is a possibility so I wanted to check here to see if anyone else has run into this and has a way to be able to select the Map key without altering the data structure of the source field.

Comment: Version is 7.1 btw

Comment: I don't think you can get the key as an output field without selecting it as if it were any other literal